# login authentication issue in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created login page and for accessing data I have used `JSON` File. when I click on the `login() btn` , userdata should match with the server data. But I am getting error and I am not able to send the $http response to the client side from server. If the rows with that name and password matches it return true, if not return false. then the client should parse this response.

But I don't know how What I am doing wrong?

Any help / advice would be greatly appreciated.

AngualJS:

```
/* server-side */

app.factory('auth', function ($http, session) {
    var authService = {};

    authService.login = function (username, password) {
        var response;
        $http.post('http://localhost:3000/loginfo')
            .then(
                function successCallback(response) {
                    var user = response.data;
                    console.log(user);
                    if (user.username == username && user.password == password) {
                        var signinfo = response.data;
                        console.log(response.data);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Error');
                    }
                })
    };

    authService.isAuthenticated = function () {
        return {
            isAuthenticated: false,
            user: null
        }
    };

    return authService;
});

/* client-side */
app.controller('credientials', function ($scope, $http, auth) {
    $scope.userCred = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    };

    /*-----Form Submition-----*/

    $scope.log = function (userCred) {
        auth.isAuthenticated = true;
        auth.login(userCred.username, userCred.password, function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                console.log('success');
            } else {
                console.log('Error');
            }
        })
    };
});
```

Comment: what do you mean with server-side? AngularJS is a purely client-side framework

Comment: server-side means , when user post the data, it should match with the json-file and get the response. To fetch that response, i have made authentication on the response content

Comment: That's not secure at all. First, you can't rely on validating the credentials client side - a visitor could simply open developer tools and change `isAuthenticated` to true. That's not the worst part though. If I understand your intention correctly, you want to load a json file with the user credentials and then validate whether the username/password pair exists in that data. That's an awful approach. Anyone could just load the json file themselves and get every users credentials. I really sincerely hope that I'm misunderstanding your intentions.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen. I know it's an bad practice. But i want to try it out. Do you have any idea to run the code

Comment: What do you want to do?       if (user.username == username && user.password == password) {
                        var signinfo = response.data;
                        console.log(response.data);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Error');
                    } this is totaly wrong

Comment: @phoine It's not just bad practice, it's highly insecure and dishonest (assuming you're going to let real people use your application). Anyone who has their credentials stored with your system will have them exposed openly to anyone. I'm not going to contribute to that.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen. I am new to angulajs . I am a learner , so i started to create small application . once i understand the flow , i will start creating authenticated site and make it secure.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen . If u have any idea , please let me know so that i can correct my mistake

Comment: Any authentication has to be done server side, whether that being your own server or some sort of external authentication service. You can't secure anything in the browser, since anyone can do anything client side using the JavaScript console. If you don't know anything about implementing secure authentication, then you just have to study it. You could start by searching for "How to do authentication in X" where X is whichever serverside technology you're using.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback  . I'll go through it @NikolajDamLarsen