# Client-side authentication using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created login page and trying to do client-side authentication. I know it's a bad practice, but I want to learn it. I am accessing the data using `JSON server`.  When I submit the button , my data is getting posted in the server, but I am failing when I am trying to match the content on success call. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Any help / advice would be greatly appreciated.

AngularJS :

```
app.factory('Authentication', function($http, $q, session) {
  var service = {};

  service.isAuthenticated = function() {
    return isAuthenticated = false,
      username = ""
  };

  service.login = function(username, password) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
      $http.post('http://localhost:3000/loginfo', {
          username,
          password
        })
        .then(
          function successCallback(response) {
            var data = response.data;
            var user = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < data; i++) {
              alert('go');
              if (data[i].username === username && data[i].password === password) {
                user = data[i];
                break;
              }
            }
            session.create(response.data.id, response.data.username);
            resolve(response.data);
            console.log(response.data)
          },
          function(err) {
            reject(err);
          });
    });
  };
  return service;
});

/* client-side */

app.controller('credientials', function($scope, $http, auth) {

  $scope.userCred = {
    username: '',
    password: ''
  };

  /*-----Form Submition-----*/

  $scope.log = function(userCred) {
    $scope.isAuthenticated = true;
    Authentication.login(userCred.username, userCred.password)
      .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      }, function(err) {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };
}]);
```

Comment: It looks like this POST to http://localhost:3000/loginfo returns the username and password (of all users??) in the response? If so, you just gave me the real password, regardless of whatever I typed in. So with one call to the service, I can obtain the correct password, making any future checks (either client- or server-side) completely redundant, because you just gave me the credentials for free. If you already know this is bad practice, why are you trying to learn it? The way you're doing it just blows a massive hole in your security and makes any kind of credential-checking pointless.

Comment: I know, But i wanted to learn it. But I am not sure how to do the authentication on client-side. If you have any demo example , please drop it @ADyson

Comment: example of what, precisely? You **can't** do the authentication on the client-side securely, because it requires you to expose the correct credentials to the client, where anyone with even basic knowledge can read them. You have to just send to the server the credentials given by the user and expect back a "yes" or "no" style of response, which does not give away the real credentials stored on the server. It is the server which must compare the submitted credentials to the stored ones. The client can **never** do this in a secure way.

Comment: P.S. I see from your history that you've asked basically the same question already a week ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730846/login-authentication-issue-in-angularjs, and it has already been explained to you that your approach is insecure and completely un-workable. I don't understand why you a) are still persisting with this despite it being clear that the whole idea is completely pointless, and b) posted a duplicate question on the same topic, when someone already gave you an explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [login authentication issue in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730846/login-authentication-issue-in-angularjs)

Comment: like you said , last week i posted this question and i got the answer. But mean while one person said , if i go through on few topics like accessing element from client side or server side i might able to solve the answer. I implemented few more steps and drop the same question @ADyson

Comment: just let me know, if this question is totally out of the box or i could possible learn and implement it. If it's yes , i just drop it here itself or else i'll try to learn it @ADyson

Comment: yes you could learn to implement it, sure...but why? It has no purpose. It does not solve any kind of problem or help with anything. In my opinion you'd be better learning to implement something which is actually useful.

Comment: Alright Thanks adyson. I'll start learning something productive @ADyson